# Mounds of earth with saris

Tags: shiva-lingam, earth

[image]Hello I hope this question isn't stupid or offensive in any way - in KZN, South Africa, the biggest Indian settlement in the world outside of India, I have recently noticed (again, as I'm sure I saw them before) low, round mounds of earth covered in saris, with sometimes a trident and bottles of water in front of them. Are these Shiva mounds, or are they connected to worship of Mother Earth, or both? I find the issue really interesting and want to share some of my photos on social media, but not without the correct explanation! Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a prayer for Lord Shiva's snake. It is called a puttu prayer. It's to keep the snake calm and content in order to avoid it causing any harm.

Comment: A picture would be helpful for us.

Comment: Is there a way I can add or upload a picture? Because I did take some.

Comment: Yes. Click the edit option under your question and click on the image on the left. Or https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/formatting. If you are using a key board, then type Ctrl+G